# JavaScript Logical OR invalid assignment

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I'm trying to understand how JavaScript's logical OR operator works and I am trying to recreate a code I read in a book but with my own twist to it but I keep getting a reference error when I try to run the code.

```
function add(a,b) {
   b || b = 1;
   return a+b;
}
```

My understanding is that if the left operand is false then the right operand is evaluated then the right operand's value is returned or used. With the code above, what I am trying to do is when the function is invoked and the second parameter is omitted, it would use a default value of 1 as the second value to the equation, but I keep getting a reference error that states invalid left hand assignment.

Comment: I sure hope they do not pass in zero.

Comment: What you are looking for is b = b || 1;

Comment: There is an error in this logic as @epascarello pointed out. So if you change it to what @HJ05 suggested `add(1,0)` will return 2.  You might want to change it to `b=b||0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). Assignment `=` has lower precedence than boolean or `||`, therefore this

```
b || b = 1
```

is interpreted as

```
(b || b) = 1
```

which is invalid, because you cannot assign to an expression. To achieve what you want you have to tell JS you want `||` first and then `=`:

```
b || (b = 1)
```

but a more common way to express this would be

```
b = b || 1
```

In the context of your function this might not work as expected, since `0` is a valid integer value, and your code will treat it as `false` and substitute it with `1`. So, the correct, although more verbose, way to write your function is

```
 function add(a, b) {
    b = (typeof b == "undefined") ? 1 : b;
    return a + b;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! I think I am getting how || works now. But I do have one question, with the operator precedence and with the expression b = b || 1 and the context of my function above, it is basically saying that assign the second parameter to the variable b then if it is not there then use the right operand of ||. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The `||` operand in assignment expression says to apply the right side of the operation if the left side evaluates to false. In the case of JavaScript `0` evaluates to false. Here are some examples of values that evaluate to false in JavaScript: http://www.javascriptexamples.org/2011/01/04/what-values-are-equivalent-to-false-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

Probably you wanna achieve this:

```
b = b || 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `b || (b = 1)` instead. That's also exactly what CoffeeScript generates for its `||=` operator.

Comment: This works, but has the same error that the other (`b = b || 1`) solution has. (Namely, `add(1,0)` produces 2 instead of 1).